# How to change the directory in python with continious loop?

Tags: python-3.x

How can set loop for changing directory continuously ?

```
import os

print(os .getcwd())
os.system('./gromacs.sh')

os.chdir('/home/abhi/screening/without_membrane/2_NS/MA_33_SCRENNING/KCATBH002/')
print(os.getcwd())
os.system ('python gromacs.py')

os.chdir('/home/abhi/screening/without_membrane/2_NS/MA_33_SCRENNING/KCATBH003/')
print(os.getcwd())
os.system('python gromacs.py')

os.chdir('/home/abhi/screening/without_membrane/2_NS/MA_33_SCRENNING/KCATBH004/')
print(os.getcwd())
os.system('python gromacs.py')

os.chdir('/home/abhi/screening/without_membrane/2_NS/MA_33_SCRENNING/KCATBH005/')
print(os.getcwd())
os.system('python gromacs.py')

os.chdir('/home/abhi/screening/without_membrane/2_NS/MA_33_SCRENNING/KCATBH006/')
print(os.getcwd())
os.system('python gromacs.py')

os.chdir('/home/abhi/screening/without_membrane/2_NS/MA_33_SCRENNING/KCATBH007/')
print(os.getcwd())
os.system('python gromacs.py')

os.chdir('/home/abhi/screening/without_membrane/2_NS/MA_33_SCRENNING/KCATBH008/')
print(os.getcwd())
os.system('python gromacs.py')

os.chdir('/home/abhi/screening/without_membrane/2_NS/MA_33_SCRENNING/KCATBH009/')
print(os.getcwd())
os.system('python gromacs.py')
```

Comment: I do not get your question, would you like to loop over all children of a directory? Or have a list of predifenied directories and loop over them?

Comment: i just want to loop over /KCATBH002  to /KCATBH003 and so on ..

Comment: Then just use a loop `for path in ['mypath', 'mysecondpath']` etc... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to loop through all the directories you want to go through?

```
var directory = '/home/abhi/screening/without_membrane/2_NS/MA_33_SCRENNING/KCATBH00'
var numOfIterations = 10 #Arbitrary value

for x in range(1, numOfIterations):
    os.chdir(directory + str(x) + '/')
    print(os.getcwd())
    os.system('python gromacs.py')
```

Comment: with little modification, it worked, with a change in range (1,10)  and str(x)